Discrepancy in “plays” count between Instagram API and app for reels with shared posts
I’m using the Instagram Graph API to retrieve the “plays” count for reels using the ig_reels_aggregated_all_plays_count field from the IG Media endpoint (documentation here). However, I’ve noticed that the “plays” count returned by the API does not match the count shown in the Instagram app. The discrepancy is particularly significant when the reel has been shared by other accounts or is a joint post by two or more accounts. The count in the app is almost twice as high as the count returned by the API.
I expected the ig_reels_aggregated_all_plays_count value returned by the API to match the “plays” count shown in the Instagram app, regardless of whether the reel was shared or jointly posted. I have verified that the API count is accurate when the reel is not shared by other accounts, but the count becomes inaccurate (almost half of what the app shows) when the reel is shared or jointly posted. I’m looking for insights into why this discrepancy occurs and if there’s a way to obtain a more accurate “plays” count through the API.
